# Wicket : How to refresh/redraw a wizard onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, wicket, wicket-1.4

I have a Wizard(`org.apache.wicket.extensions.wizard.Wizard`) that has an `AjaxButton` as its Next Button.

I am performing a long running operation on `onSubmit()` method of next button.
Before exiting from the method I am using `ajaxTarget.appendJavascript(js)` where `ajaxTarget` is `AjaxRequestTarget` and `js` is a JavaScript snippet that I want to be evaluated.

Now, as far as I know, this script won't get executed until `onSubmit()´ has returned and the response is send back to the browser.

How can I execute my JavaScript immediately without waiting for `onSubmit` to have finished?

Note: I am using Wicket-4

Answer (score 1):

> this script won't get executed until the wizard is redrawn/refreshed.

All appended JavaScript snippets are executed once the AjaxRequest has finished - the wizard itself does not need to be updated.

If you're executing a long running task from your Ajax request, the browser's Ajax request will eventually run into a timeout.
You should move your long running task onto a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that all the snippets are executed once the AjaxRequest has finished. However, in my case the request finishes before completion of onSubmit() method.
I tried adding component using the ways you suggested but it isn't working.
I am new to wicket and I might be doing something silly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So #onSubmit() isn't called at all? Then you have validation errors in your form.

Comment: OnSubmit() is called. One minute into the execution, the Ajax call is completed but the onSubmit function is still executing.

Comment: I see, you're executing a long running task.

Comment: Yes. And I want the javascript to be executed after the task has finished. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See the last article at wicketinaction.com. it is about this topic